# .NET Assembly dependency version fallback

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, assemblies

So I have a GUI application (C# .NET 4.0), which we'll call main.exe.  It is dependent on class library we'll call library.dll (C#  .NET 3.5) with several shipped versions (we'll say 1.1.0.0, 1.2.0.0 and 1.3.0.0). One (or more) versions of library.dll will be installed in the GAC of the target environment.  All involved assemblies are strongly named.

My goal here is for main.exe to use whichever version of library.dll is available, and if possible to attempt to use the latest version if possible.  However I am working under a few restrictions:

1. library.dll is an existing assembly and cannot be changed at this point.
2. main.exe (which can change) is designed with hard dependencies, Assembly.LoadWithPartialName() or something along those lines would be a prohibitive design change.

Optimally, I am looking for a mechanism along the lines of an assembly redirect, but I haven't found a way to finagle the configuration properly for this scenario.

Given that we build against library 1.1.0.0, it would be nice if either of these redirect setups worked, but alas they don't.

```
    <?xml version ="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <!-- 
                intent here is to provide a range of possible installed assemblies
                but .NET does not allow ranges in newVersion 
            -->
            <assemblyIdentity name="library" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0-1.3.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <!-- 
                intent here is to provide a fallback list of possible installed assemblies
                but .NET ignore all but the first bindingRedirect
            -->
            <assemblyIdentity name="library" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```